# How to insert record in cassandra table using airflow?

Tags: docker, cassandra, airflow

I have installed Cassandra in docker along with airflow.

I want to insert data in the Cassandra table using airflow.

Just like airflow has MySqlOperator to install data in SQL table, so is there any operator or way to insert records into Cassandra table.

I found only these two operators:
from airflow.providers.apache.cassandra.sensors.record import CassandraRecordSensor
from airflow.providers.apache.cassandra.sensors.table import CassandraTableSensor

But these operators are just to check tables or record existence in cassandra.

So, how to insert or let say interact with Cassandra using airflow tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation shows that indeed there are no "write" operations implemented:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-apache-cassandra/stable/operators.html

But Apache Airflow is really easy to extend if you do not have ready-to-use operator.

You need to either extend Cassandra Hook and implement custom operator (and possibly contribute it back to the community when you do) if you know your Python ways. This is best as you will be able to use cassandra libraries and authentication that is already there I guess.

Or you might use BashOperator to run CQL commands (I believe this is the default client that cassandra uses). For example if you have CSV file you can import it using COPY command in CQL.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCopy.html

Then you have to do some linking between authentication information from connection and pass it to the BashOperator or maybe provide your own way how to authenticate with Cassandra.

Comment: I tried your first solution that is to create a custom Cassandra operator. Only problem is that I'm not able to import CassandraHook, it gives an error. I tried these 2 ways:
from airflow.providers.apache.cassandra.hooks.cassandra import CassandraHook
from airflow.contrib.hooks.cassandra_hook import CassandraHook

What is the right approach to extend CassandraHook?

Comment: If you are on Airlfow 1.10 - upgrade to Airflow 2 . Airflow 1.10 reached end of life in June and it will not get any more fixes - even critical security fixes. So upgrade to Airflow 2 as soon as possible. If you are on 2 you need to install 'apache-airflow-providers-apache-cassandra' to get those packages. Airflow 2 has been split to "core" airflow and ~ 70 providers.